# Relationships in JPA. How does they internally work?

Tags: jpa, relationships

For example, these classes:

```
public class Boss{
    ... 
    @OneToMany(mappedBy="boss")
    Set<Employee> employees;
}

public class Employee{
    @ManyToOne
    Boss boss;
    ...
}
```

There is a relationship between Boss and Employee. I can find all the employees from a Boss, doing boss.getEmployees().

What does SDFDK do to  know the elements of a relationship? Save the id of all employees from a boss?

I would like to know the difference in performance between boss.getEmployees(), and a query with "SELECT e FROM Employee e where e.id='boss_id' "

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I would like to know the difference in performance between
>   boss.getEmployees(), and a query with "SELECT e FROM Employee e where
>   e.id='boss_id' "

Difference is yes in performance but works same. `JPA` is slower than `JDBC` of course. `JDBC` is also on lower level than `JPA`. I tell you this. An usage of `ORM` has one main advantage and that you will save a lot of time with implementation of your own `ORM` but you don't have as much control over queries as with if you implement your own `ORM`. You know nothing about internal implementation of methods and other stuff of `JPA`.

When you implement your own `ORM` you have much more control over queries, you can optimize queries based on application requirements but it takes some time. `JPA` is `ORM` framework that implements all required db logic instead you. You just need to tell him what you want via annotations.

Next advantage of `ORM` frameworks is that your application will become independent on database layer(type of datasource) but also you can achieve this by implementation of proper design patterns like `AbstractDAOFactory`, `AbstractDataMapper` etc.